# Remove text labels in Plotly Sankey diagram, but keep the data when hovering [Plotly Python Sankey question]

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python, sankey-diagram

I want to keep the labels when you hover, but hide the labels from just appearing over the Sankey as text.

Here is my code:

```
labels = df_mapping['Name'].to_numpy().tolist() + labels
count_dict = {}
source = []
target = []
value = df_subset['Stuff'].to_numpy().tolist()
index = 0
for x in unique_broad:
    count_dict[x] = len(df_mapping.loc[df_mapping['Stuff'] == x])
for key in count_dict:
    for i in range(count_dict[key]):
        source.append(index)
        index += 1
for key in count_dict:
    for i in range(count_dict[key]):
        target.append(index)
    index += 1
number_of_colors = len(source)
color_link = ["#"+''.join([random.choice('0123456789ABCDEF') for j in range(6)])
             for i in range(number_of_colors)]
link = dict(source=source, target=target, value=value, color=color_link)
node = dict(label=labels, pad=35, thickness=10)
data = go.Sankey(link=link, node=node)
fig = go.Figure(data)
fig.update_layout(
    hovermode = 'x',
    title="Sankey for Stuff",
    font=dict(size=8, color='white'),
    paper_bgcolor='#51504f'
)
return fig
```

[image: Picture of what needs to change]

Comment: https://plotly.com/python/sankey-diagram/ link to what I am using for reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the labels invisible by setting the color of the labels to `rgba(0,0,0,0)`. This ensures that the label will remain in the hovertemplate, but not show up on the nodes.

To do this you can pass `textfont=dict(color="rgba(0,0,0,0)", size=1)` to `go.Sankey` such as in the example you used from the Plotly sankey diagram documentation:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import urllib.request, json

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/plotly.js/master/test/image/mocks/sankey_energy.json'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())

# override gray link colors with 'source' colors
opacity = 0.4
# change 'magenta' to its 'rgba' value to add opacity
data['data'][0]['node']['color'] = ['rgba(255,0,255, 0.8)' if color == "magenta" else color for color in data['data'][0]['node']['color']]
data['data'][0]['link']['color'] = [data['data'][0]['node']['color'][src].replace("0.8", str(opacity))
                                    for src in data['data'][0]['link']['source']]

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
    textfont=dict(color="rgba(0,0,0,0)", size=1),
    valueformat = ".0f",
    valuesuffix = "TWh",
    # Define nodes
    node = dict(
      pad = 15,
      thickness = 15,
      line = dict(color = "black", width = 0.5),
      label =  data['data'][0]['node']['label'],
      color =  data['data'][0]['node']['color']
    ),
    # Add links
    link = dict(
      source =  data['data'][0]['link']['source'],
      target =  data['data'][0]['link']['target'],
      value =  data['data'][0]['link']['value'],
      label =  data['data'][0]['link']['label'],
      color =  data['data'][0]['link']['color']
))])

fig.update_layout(title_text="Energy forecast for 2050<br>Source: Department of Energy & Climate Change, Tom Counsell via <a href='https://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/'>Mike Bostock</a>",
                  font_size=10)
fig.show()
```

You get the following:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is great. One quick follow up question. Is there a way to have the source nodes as invisible labels but display the target labels?